# Overlay/overlap elements

Tags: html, css

See my code:

```
<table id="preview_table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="not_mapped_style" style="display: none; text-align: center;">id</th>
  <th init_value="Name" style="text-align: center;" class="">
      <div class="mapped_col">mapped!</div>
      <div class="col_name">DisplayName</div>
      <div class="user_def_col">(user defined)</div>
  </th>
  <th init_value="Email" style="text-align: center;" class="">
      <div class="mapped_col">mapped!</div>
      <div class="col_name">PrimaryEmail</div>
      <div class="user_def_col">(user defined)</div>
  </th>
  <th init_value="Age" style="text-align: center;" class="">
      <div class="mapped_col">mapped!</div>
      <div class="col_name">Age</div>
      <div class="user_def_col">(user defined)</div>
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<caption>List</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="display: none;" property_value="0" property_name="id" align="center">0</td>
  <td class="" property_value="user" property_name="DisplayName" align="center">user</td>
  <td class="" property_value="admin@domain.com" property_name="PrimaryEmail" align="center">admin@domain.com</td>
  <td class="" property_value="69" property_name="Age" align="center">69</td>
  <td class="" property_value="+722616807" property_name="Hand_Phone" align="center">+722616807</td>
</tr>  
</tbody>
```

here is CSS:

```
#preview_table .user_def_col {
color: gray;
font-size: .8em;
}

#preview_table .mapped_col {
color: green;
font-size: .6em;
float: right;    
position: relative;
top: -10px;    
}
```

Currently my **mapped!** text corrupts centering for column header names. I wonder is that possible to overlay **mapped!** text over header column name (e.g. **Age**) while column name remain centered by it cell by width?

Answer (score 0):

You can put "mapped!" into a `span` and use [absolute positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) (parent cell would need to have `position:relative`)

Comment: In this case ALL mine "mapped!" (it's 4 now) will be positioned in the same place.

Comment: Not if every parent will have `position:relative`, in this case `<th>`. Then it's up to you how you style and position them, but it will allow you to place 'mapped' in the same place relatively to its parent

Comment: 1) ok, but even in this case _mapped_ position will depend on column name text so will be positioned in different places of header cell; 2) Even with _position:relative_ for _th_ this doesn't work - all mine "_mapped!_" are positioned relatively entire page but not _th_ cell!

Comment: I've udated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qShva/3/)  "mapped!" are absolutely positioned to the right in `<th>`

Comment: It's strange but it is not work for me. Maybe because I have absolute/relative positioned elements at parent elements?

Comment: If parent has `position` set in css at all, it should work. Try to add `top:0px` and `left:0px` to "mapped!" just to see its "default" position

Comment: I've tried already _top:0px_ and _left:0px_ are positioned on page edjes

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code. I changed the font-size and added color to rows, so that the UI is visible properly..

```
<table id="preview_table">
<caption>List</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="not_mapped_style" style="display: none; text-align: center;">id</th>
  <th init_value="Name" style="text-align: center;" class="">
      <div class="col_name">DisplayName</div>
      <div class="user_def_col">(user defined)</div>
      <div class="mapped_col">MAPPED!!!!</div>
  </th>
  <th init_value="Email" style="text-align: center;" class="">
      <div class="col_name">PrimaryEmail</div>
      <div class="user_def_col">(user defined)</div>
      <div class="mapped_col">MAPPED!!!!</div>
  </th>
  <th init_value="Age" style="text-align: center;" class="">
      <div class="col_name">Age</div>
      <div class="user_def_col">(user defined)</div>
      <div class="mapped_col">MAPPED!!!!</div>
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="display: none;" property_value="0" property_name="id" align="center">0</td>
  <td class="" property_value="user" property_name="DisplayName" align="center">user</td>
  <td class="" property_value="admin@domain.com" property_name="PrimaryEmail" align="center">admin@domain.com</td>
  <td class="" property_value="69" property_name="Age" align="center">69</td>
  <td class="" property_value="+722616807" property_name="Hand_Phone" align="center">+722616807</td>
</tr>  
</tbody>
</table​>
```

**CSS:**

```
#preview_table .user_def_col {
color: gray;
font-size: 15px;
}

#preview_table .mapped_col {
color: green;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
    margin-top: -20px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
tr
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
​
```

Comment: It doesn't work. 1) Try to position _MAPPED!!!_ to the same line as column name - it will not work; 2) What is key CSS solution here? 3) Why you copy-pasted mine code to your answer?

Comment: There are 3 html changes. I moved the mapped!! div to down. And also some css change is done. Did you check the fiddle given in the previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it. It has mess HTML result with overlapped elements that do not able to be positioned in custom way.